# Android: How to post update on Facebook wall automatically?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I want my android application to automatically post a preset message when the user click on a button. The preset message will be set by the user, so I am guessing that is not a violation of Facebook policies. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket/

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
    new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"};


Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);


postButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        authenticatedFacebook.authorize(Tests.this, PERMISSIONS,
            new TestPostListener());
    }
});


public class TestPostListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        try {
            Log.d("Tests", "Testing request for 'me'");
            String response = authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
            JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);

            Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "Amit Siddhpura");
            parameters.putString("description", "Hi Mr. Amit Siddhpura");
            response = authenticatedFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onCancel() {
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(6358): Caused by: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_stream) to a request for read authorization

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Application on Facebook

And get authenticate from user, then you can get a access_token to post some message through Graph API

I think your application have to request extended permissions : publish_stream, offline_access

There is Facebook-Android-SDK source code on github, you can refer it.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile

Comment: Thankyou. But can you please point me to some code that I could use. I do not know how to actually implement this in java. The documentation is all greek and latin to me :(

Comment: I have less reputation, so I can't post more link on article. You can just try this: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk